# Node.js fs - why is this check required?

Tags: node.js

Why is the `errored` variable required?

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = function (dir, cb) {
  fs.readdir(dir, function (er, files) { // [1]
    if (er) return cb(er)
    var counter = files.length
    var errored = false
    var stats = []

    files.forEach(function (file, index) {
      fs.stat(path.join(dir,file), function (er, stat) { // [2]
        if (errored) return
        if (er) {
          errored = true
          return cb(er)
        }
        stats[index] = stat // [3]

        if (--counter == 0) { // [4]
          var largest = stats
            .filter(function (stat) { return stat.isFile() }) // [5]
            .reduce(function (prev, next) { // [6]
              if (prev.size > next.size) return prev
              return next
            })
          cb(null, files[stats.indexOf(largest)]) // [7]
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Code from a blog entry at http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators. There it says: "errored boolean to prevent the provided callback (cb) from being called more than once if an error occurs". Can someone explain this for me? Under what circumstances might cb be called more than once?

Comment: To stop early in case you get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, whoever wrote that code don't want to iterate over all files in the `forEach` when a file is throwing an error on `fs.stat`.

When a file did throw an error on `fs.stat`, all following iterations in the `forEach` are going to return (`if (errored) return`).

The variable is not **required** but we'll say it's cleaner this way.

To answer to your edit, the callback is fired for each element in the `files` array.